# В Mozilla FF не работает функция jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, firefox

Есть div блок, отвечающий за всплывающее меню.

```
<div class="pop-up">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="bandit in bandits">{{bandit.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

И есть элемент меню, при наведении мыши на которое, должно появляться меню.

```
<li id="we">
    <div>
        <h4>Мы</h4>
        <span>Кто мы такие</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Обработчики наведений на меню и li-элемент.

```
$(function() {

    $('#we').hover(function () {
        if ($('.pop-up').css('display') === 'none') {// если блок меню не отображен, то отобразить
            $('.pop-up').slideDown(500);
        } 
    }, function () {
        if ($(".pop-up").is(":hover")) {    // если после li мы навели курсором на меню, то
            $(this).css('display', 'block'); // сделать его блочным.    
        } else {
            $('.pop-up').slideUp(500);  // в другом случае, спрятать.
        }
    });

    $('.pop-up').hover(function () {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    },
    function () {
        if (!$("#we").is(":hover"))
        $('.pop-up').slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

Во всех браузерах все работает отлично, кроме mozilla.
В нем `$(".pop-up").is(":hover")` возвращает false, даже если мы навели курсор на меню. В чем проблема?

Comment: `if($(".pop-up:hover").length > 0) { $(".pop-up:hover").css('display', 'block'); } else {
            $('.pop-up').slideUp(500); 
        }`

Comment: @MasterAlex, а в чём проблема с Firefox и jquery?

Comment: ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: FF возвращает true http://jsbin.com/tuxobisape/edit?html,output